# How to export multiple layers each combined with a clipping mask, in an efficient manner (in Photoshop)?

Tags: export, mask

In my photoshop program I have 182 background layers. I have a total of 20 different masks that I want to apply to each layer. So that I get a background layer and mask combination.

What is the best way for me to apply the masks to each background layer so the combinations can be exported? I prefer not to manually export each combination as this is a lot of manual labor.

Any suggestions as to how I can set-up the masks and/or export the combinations efficiently?

P.S. I am not very experienced in Photoshop so specfic suggestions are appreciated

Comment: You can group layers and apply a mask on the group. Or if you need to do this a lot of times automating something like this with the Actions panel should be possible as well.